# Show that a vector space with an action on $G$ is a representation of $G$ if and only if ...

Tags: representation-theory

I don't know how to show this exercise. I don't think I understand what they want me to show. I thought it was a definition.

Exercise: 
Let $V$ be a vector space with an action of $G$. Show that this is a representation of $G$ if and only if the following hold for all $v \in V$, for all $w \in V$ and all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$:

1. $g(v+w) =gv+gw$
2. $g(\lambda v)= \lambda(gv)$.

Comment: If you look up the definition of a representation from your course/book/notes and edit it into the question, you're much more likely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A representation is a group homomorphism $\rho:G\to GL(V)$, where $GL(V)$ is the group of invertible linear transformations $T:V\to V$.

The action of $G$ on $V$ defines a map $T_g:V\to V$ for each $g\in G$ given by $T_g(v)=g.v$. These maps are bijections (i.e. elements of $Sym(V)$), but not linear in general. However, the two assumptions above imply that these maps are linear since
$$
T_g(v+w)=g.(v+w)=g.v+g.w=T_g(v)+T_g(w)
$$
and
$$
T_g(\lambda v)=g.(\lambda v)=\lambda g.v=\lambda T_g(v).
$$

Therefore, the assignment $g\mapsto T_g$ defines a map $G\to GL(V)$. The standard properties of a group action imply that this map is a homomorphism--since $g.(h.v)=(gh).v$ we have
$$
T_gT_h(v)=T_g(h.v)=g.(h.v)=(gh).v=T_{gh}(v).
$$

Conversely, if a group action defines a homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$, $g\mapsto T_g$, then the fact that $T_g$ is a linear transformation implies the two conditions above.

Answer (score 0):

A representation of $G$ on a vector space $V$ is the same as a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{End}(V)$, where $\mathrm{End}(V)$ are the endomorphmisms of $V$. Note that this map is *linear*.

But an *action* is just a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}{V}$ (as a free group).

I think the exercise asks you to show that a representation is an action that lands in the endomorphism group of $V$.